# ReentrantLock - Is this a valid approach to using it

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I have two methods both run by different threads, one of the methods i dont want to run when the other has been called. This is the reason I have chosen to use a lock

```
@Override
public synchronized void doSomething(int[] params)
{
    while (lock.isLocked())
    {
        // wait for it to become unlocked
    }

    //lock is released so lets do some stuff
```

in my other method I have the following implementation

```
@Override
public void doSomethingElse(int param)
{
    lock.lock();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < param; i++)
    {
       //do some stuff
    }
    lock.unlock();
}
```

Is the while loop the correct way to say, I want this thread to wait here until the lock is released or is there a better way to implement this

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The while loop does busy waiting, which is definitely something you don't want to do.
Calling `lock.lock();` will block until the lock is released, so it's the proper way to do it, just like you're doing in your other method.

You also don't need for the first method to be `synchronized`, and the lock should always be released in a `finally` clause.

Answer (score 2):

You need something like this:

```
private void method1()
{
    lock.lock();
    try {
        ...
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}

private void method2()
{
    lock.lock();
    try {
        ...
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Don't forgeet to use try {} finally{} or you could end up with deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

Both wrong, the standard practice is to unlock in the finally clause. Otherwise the application will stall if exception is thrown from inside the code where the lock applies:

```
public void doSomethingElse(int param) throws Exception {
    lock.lock();
    try {
       //do some stuff that may throw exceptions
    } finally {
      lock.unlock(); 
    } 
}
```